# Fineuploader with Lambda for Signing S3 request

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, fine-uploader

I am trying to upload large files to S3 in chunks. This needs to be done via browser. I was looking at FineUploader as solution. https://fineuploader.com/

It would need a Signing function which gives me the correct Authorization header.

This is specified in FineUploader as :

```
signature: {
        endpoint: "/s3/signtureHandler",
        version: 4
}
```

I saw the current examples have Servlet and PHP. I wanted to to know if we can get the same achieved by a Lambda function exposed by an API Gateway.

Has anyone tried it before or know of any potential pitfalls?

Comment: http://blog.stratospark.com/secure-serverless-file-uploads-with-aws-lambda-s3-zappa.html

Comment: Thanks Ray for the reply ( and for a great library as well !!).. I was actually looking for a pure lambda solution (no other frameworks) and preferably in Java.. I have finally been able to get it up and running with API Gateway and AWS Lambda..

Comment: @Manish if you know the answer, you should probably answer your question for others.

Comment: @Manish you should write your solution as an answer.